# How to temporary hide HTML character for a translation of a text?

Tags: html, google-api

We have a E-Commerce Shop (JTL Software) and like to expand to 3 different Countries.

For that we need to translate EVERY of our 5000 products in that language.

So my idea is to export every articel decription and auto translate it in a excel sheet and then reimport it.

I am Exporting a CSV File where in every cell is the description of the Article we sell and this description contains the html formatting, so all the characters.

We export it from our Merchandise Management System JTL Software.

Then we'd like to use the Google API to translate every cell description in englisch, france, spain.

But for that we need to get rid of the HTML Characters, otherwise Google could misinterpret someting like
,

, <a href=""=>.

But after the translation we need to get these characters back in the cell at the place they've been before because without the HTML Character, we wouldn't have our translation formatted.

We than reimport every column with it translated cells into JTL Software and assign it to the language.

So what could be a solution to this task ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the `[<>]` [snippet editor](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do).

Comment: Remember that SO is a Q&A style website, not a forum, so your question should give all the information needed to answer without needing back-and-forth conversation. As it stands, we can't begin to guess where you data is stored and what you mean by import and export.

Comment: And how/where do you use `google-api` ?